# Deploy App Under Sub-directory - Azure

Tags: azure

I have a microservices application in a sub folder of github repository. I am trying to deploy it to Azure.

I found that if I add `.deployment` file in my root directory, Azure will automatically deploy the application found under the given path. [Here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-aspnet-or-aspnet-core-project-file)

I have tried the following,

```
[config]
project = myFlaskProject/helloFlask
```

Azure build the project successfully, but still it gives me `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` Not sure why, any ideas?

P.S. It works fine if I keep all the application files in my root directory.

Here is the demo testing repository I have made. [Hello World Flash Repo](https://github.com/temurih/python-docs-hello-world)

And here is the [live demo](https://asdfhg.azurewebsites.net/) of the site.

Here are the build logs from Azure,

```
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --python --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository\flask\helloWorld"'.
The site directory path: .\flask\helloWorld
Generating deployment script for python Web Site
Generated deployment script files

Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling python deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'requirements.txt'
Copying file: 'web.2.7.config'
Copying file: 'web.3.4.config'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\.gitignore'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\index.html'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\main.py'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\README.md'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\requirements.txt'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\web.2.7.config'
Copying file: 'flask\helloWorld\web.3.4.config'
Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file.
Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
Detected python-2.7
Found compatible virtual environment.
Pip install requirements.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.12.1 in d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Cleaning up...
Overwriting web.config with web.2.7.config
        1 file(s) copied.
Finished successfully.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in python deployment of Azure. But there is a work around it until they fix it. [Read my issue here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2661)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with Spring Rest Controller
and I plugged it directly in config
eg in yml:

```
run: mvn clean install -f subDirectory/pom.xml
```

I am not sure if this is considered best practice but, it worked for me.